# Can you multiclass out of your starting class if you don't have the required stats for it?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, ability-scores

I am aware that you can only multiclass ***into*** a class that you have the required stats for (ex : dex 13 + wis 13 to multiclass into monk).

I am also aware that your initial class can be one that you wouldn't have the required stats to multiclass into in the first place (ex: start as a wizard with an INT of 12). You can continue to get levels in that initial class as long as you don't multiclass, but after that, you can't get additional levels in that starting class (unless you then meet the requirements).

However, someone recently told me that if you don't have the requirements for your initial class, you cannot multiclass at all (or in other words, you cannot multiclass ***out of*** your starting class if you don't meet its requirements). Is that true ?

Comment: I'm away from books at the moment and can't remember if this is covered: would a magic item that indefinitely raises the relevant ability score (e.g. headband of intellect for the aforementioned wizard) be a solution to this?

Comment: @tardigrade That's something I've often wondered myself. I just looked it up and found this: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53637/can-multi-classing-prerequisite-ability-scores-be-met-through-a-magic-item/69673#69673

Comment: Excellent - that's that sorted then! If you add this as an answer you'll be getting +1 from me.

Comment: @tardigrade Well, it's not really an answer to _this_ question since it's not about magic items specifically, also I'd essentially just be stealing credit from PurpleMonkey. Still, now we both know the answer, anyway...

Comment: @NathanS well, it's up to you - I'd argue "yes, as long as you have a stat-boosting magic item" would definitely be an answer to this, but given that it's a "no" maybe you're right.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The multi-classing rules say on PHB page 163, under “Prerequisites”:

> To qualify for a new class, you must meet the ability score
>   prerequisites for **both** your **current class and your new
>   one**, as shown in the Multiclassing Prerequisites table.

Emphasis mine. You do in fact have to meet the prerequisites for BOTH classes if you want to multiclass, whoever told you that is correct.

It's important to note that stat boosts from items that aren't permanent, such as Ogre Gauntlets, [do not count as meeting the stat requirements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53637/can-multi-classing-prerequisite-ability-scores-be-met-through-a-magic-item/69673#69673). (Thanks to tardigrade for pointing that out.)